# The command that "help @zset" in Redis is not work

Tags: redis

[image]

I want to search the usage of "zset", and then I find it doesn't work.

How can I search the usage of "zset"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of *zset*, the group name for sorted set commands is **sorted-set** (Redis 7.0 or later) or **sorted_set** (Before Redis 7.0), depending on the version of redis-cli.

So you can try the following command: `help @sorted-set` or `help @sorted_set`.

Comment: Thank you!“help @sorted_set" is succeed.My redis version is 6.2.8.